# Gatling to InfluxDB connection in windows

Tags: influxdb, gatling

I am using gatling and influxdb in windows 10. I am trying to send some results from gatling to influxdb. But the results are not being pushed to the influxdb. Can someone help me.

My graphite config file

```
data {
#writers = [console, file, graphite]      
console {
  #light = false            
  #writePeriod = 5    
}

file {
  bufferSize = 8192            # FileDataWriter's internal data buffer size, in bytes
}

leak {
  #noActivityTimeout = 30  # Period, in seconds, for which Gatling may have no activity before considering a leak may be happening
}
graphite {
 # light = false              # only send the all* stats
  host = "localhost"         # The host where the Carbon server is located
  port = 2003                # The port to which the Carbon server listens to (2003 is default for plaintext, 2004 is default for pickle)
  protocol = "tcp"           # The protocol used to send data to Carbon (currently supported : "tcp", "udp")
  rootPathPrefix = "gatling" # The common prefix of all metrics sent to Graphite
  bufferSize = 8192          # Internal data buffer size, in bytes
  writePeriod = 1            # Write period, in seconds
}
}
```

My influxdb config file is

```
[[graphite]]

enabled = true
database = "gatlingdb"
retention-policy = ""
bind-address = ":2003"
protocol = "tcp"
consistency-level = "one"


batch-size = 5000

batch-pending = 10

batch-timeout = "1s"

udp-read-buffer = 0

separator = "."


templates = [
"gatling.*.*.*.count measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
"gatling.*.*.*.min measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
"gatling.*.*.*.max measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
"gatling.*.*.*.percentiles50 measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
"gatling.*.*.*.percentiles75 measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
"gatling.*.*.*.percentiles95 measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
"gatling.*.*.*.percentiles99 measurement.simulation.request.status.field"
 ]
```

Not sure why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment `#writers = [console, file, graphite]`